# Run javascript from swf on DVD?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a project I am doing that requires delivery on a DVD and through the web. I have been using Flash to drive a menu system and javascript to load pages or other actions on the web. However, when I move it to a DVD I receive a Security Error 2060 - the swf is unable to 
communicate with the html page it is loaded onto and so none of the javascript is parsed. I am using ExternalInterface calls and jquery on the html page.

Searching online I have made sure that Flash when publishing "Allow local files only" and on the html page I'm using swfobject with a param field of allowscriptaccess of "always" - looking at the generated code on pages it shows that the allowscriptaccess is there.

Is there some security setting that I can program in that will give my Flash application the ability to function the same from a DVD as it would from the web and communicate with Javascript? If I need to compile two different swfs that would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are having a local sandbox problem.  Have you gone through the information at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/security.html?

If you can do PC-only, then investigate [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/).  This is a standalone WAMP stack that works well from a CD/DVD.  Your page will then run in the internet zone, and you should not run into the same security problems.